# creating a report on the mysql jasperReport server

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, reporting

I have mysql local database, in it I have sample data mart. I have installed jasperReport server to my computer. Just using this tool, I want connect to the local mysql database and just create a pdf report or any report without using any tool except jasperReport server. Can I do ? HOw?

Note; report will be directly constructed on the whole data reside in the mysql database. (No filtering) I want to see the report on the jasperReport report page. If any change occur on the mysql database, it should be carried out on the report page of the JAsperReport server

Answer (score 1):

You must first create a report using iReport (the report designer) i don't remember if it comes included in the Jasper Server, but if it doesn't you can download it from Jasper's web site; after that using the same iReport you must deploy the report to your Jasper Server. If you need more guidance on deploying a report you can look here: http://randomallsorts.blogspot.mx/2009/12/jasper-reports-how-to-deploy-report-to.html